# Openstack Ussuri introspection image missing raid drivers for mptsas

Tags: openstack, tripleo

I have a very ancient hardware with a MPTSAS controller. I use this for TripleO deployment testing. With the release of Ussuri which is running CentOS8, I can no longer provision my overcloud nodes as the MPTSAS driver has been removed in CentOS8:

https://www.reddit.com/r/CentOS/comments/d93unk/centos8_and_removal_mpt2sas_dell_sas_drivers/

Is there a way to modify the introspection image to include the driver? I found some documentation how to customize the overcloud-full.qcow2 image but very basic stuff like changing the root password. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Oliver